# What is board installation mean?

Tags: install

Hi today I got email from a security research program.

Yesterday I asked "Did you interested insecure permission vulnerability on ... that allow "Guests User" have full permission?"

They answer: "We interested in privilege escalation via software that has broad installations, the escalation should be non-user-interactive and gain you SYSTEM or equivalent access"

My Question is what is board installation mean? Is that mean the software that has installed on OS by default like notepad, paint?

Comment: This is not a security question but an English question. "broad installations" means "used by lots of people". They are not interested in software that no one uses. And this should be a question that you ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software that has broad installations simply means widely-used software. It does not refer to default existing OS packages (like notepad in your example). It means general use software that usually everyone has, like Adobe reader, 7Zip, the MS office package.

Vulnerabilities in such software are always hunted and well priced because that software is on a lot of PCs and exploiting it is very efficient as it has a lot of user coverage.

Comment: Exploiting means there was taken advantage of a vulnerability by the threat-source , why is exploiting software important to the efficiency of software

Comment: A project like the open-source TOR has heavily filled community with members that regularly audit their security , and sometimes they *find* a vuln and do *patch* it. The only reason TOR is such a robust, hardened, reliable and efficient browser is because of the many members/non-members that regularly find a vuln in TOR but exploiting can be useful in some cases whereby more information is needed or such. just an example.